# Mouse hover on disabled button

Tags: gwt

I have a disabled button. On mouse hover of this disabled button, I need to display a popup using GWT.
I tried to wrap it inside a panel and coded mouse hover for the panel. But it's not working instantly all the time.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should try to avoid this situation. For example, if you just want to show a small tooltip you can use a different title for enabled and disabled state explaining the disabled cause.

If you still want to react to an over event on disable button you can use something like this.

```
SimplePanel p = new SimplePanel();
Button b = new Button("hover me to toggle disable"); p.add(b);
p.addDomHandler(ev -> button.setEnabled(!b.isEnabled()), MouseOverEvent.getType());
RootPanel.get().add(p);
```

Although as you already have noticed, the browser does not fire over events on disabled inputs. So if you move the mouse without passing through the panel and goes directly to the button you will not receive the event. You can fix this applying this style.

```
button.gwt-Button[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

But probably this might have some downsides or might not work in all browsers.